# CSS file not linking to HTML file, path and order seem correct

Tags: html, css

I have my layout.html file in the 'templates' directory and my styles.css file in the 'static' directory. Both are in my project folder named 'books-cs50w'.  does not work though. I ve probably read all the google-able posts on absolute and relative paths, but for some reason my css is not applied to my layout.html. I had it at the bottom and and at the top of my bootstrap-stylesheets to make sure it's not a matter of being overwritten. To test the actual CSS, I pasted the code directly in -tags inside the layout.html file - it works. But no matter what I do when it's external - it won't read it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
```

The CSS to test it is:

```
img  {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

h1, h2 {
 color: red;
 background-color: green;
}

body, head {background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc4Nx.png)

Comment: open page in browser and press f12 and in console panel see file is load correct or no?

Comment: <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> == $0 --- I guess that means no. I know it doesn't because when I paste the css code in style-tags directly into the html, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go one level up from your current `templates` folder by prepending `../` to your css path and now that you're one level up and currently in the main `books-cs50w` project folder, you can just navigate to your `static` folder and access the css file.

Change this line:

```
<link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

To this:

```
<link href="../static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: I tried that :( i also troed moving the styles.css around, also into the same folder and just refeencing it by "styles.css". Doesn't work.

Comment: @Anna Which code editor are you using? Most code editors have a branch on the left side showing the file structure. Can you screenshot that branch and post it along with your question.

Comment: Yes, of course. I use Atom. Just uploaded the image above. @AndrewL64